# Text Summarization Tool

Tags: computational-linguistics, software, summarization

I'm looking for tools I can use to perform text summarization. Specifically something I could use to summarize personal communication (i.e. email).

Preferably I'm looking for something open source and cross platform (Java?), but I'm open to any suggestion regardless of language or cost.

Any primers/hints on specific techniques or approaches that might work best would also be appreciated.

Comment: As I recall, Microsoft Word includes a text summarization tool that does a surprisingly reasonable (though by no means perfect) job, with adjustable parameters.

Comment: Thanks @johnlawlerinexile, but I'm looking for a library I can use in making my own application.

Comment: I concur with curiousdannii.   This question does not appear to concern linguistics.

Comment: That's fair, [I did try there first](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/17686/text-summarization-on-android), but didn't get any responses.

Comment: @Fozefy Android is a tough requirement :)

Comment: True, but even a Web API or another language would be a good start. Its much easier to access an external library than to write a summary library.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [SoftwareRecs.se].

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tool I happened upon recently: [Context-controllable Content Summarization](http://genopharmix.com/TuataraSum/algorithms.html)

And this looks to be related background information:

- [Generating content summarizations similar to the way a human might do so](http://genopharmix.com/biomimetic-cognition/in_silico_cognitive_biomimicry.html)
- [Word2Vec is based on an approach from Lawrence Berkeley National Lab](https://www.kaggle.com/c/word2vec-nlp-tutorial/forums/t/12349/word2vec-is-based-on-an-approach-from-lawrence-berkeley-national-lab)
- https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/

Comment: Thanks for the attempt @arjan, but this isn't quite what I'm looking for.

The sources at genopharmix.com are a bit too specific to 'life sciences', the tool provided allows you to specify context, but that can't be a requirement when the targeted area is personal communication. It could contain info for any context.

The second source, Word2Vec, is interesting, but I'm hoping to find something more 'out of the box'. For example http://libots.sourceforge.net/ or https://github.com/Rotten194/summarize.py. Those are just a bit out-dated/primitive, so I'm hoping to find something more recent.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to do much if you are going to make an `Extractive summarization`.

1. Do stop-word Removal
2. Do stemming (optional)
3. Count all words occurrences
4. Extract sentence(s) that contains the word with most frequency in the text

This is the basic of text summarization which suits for emails very well, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You could get your summaries by using an API. It's easy to integrate in almost any app. I use this and it works.

https://market.mashape.com/textanalysis/text-summarization

You send the text and the number of sentences you want returned. You can even try it to see if it works for you. Here's the [address](http://textsummarization.net/text-summarizer) where you can evaluate it.